# ImportError: cannot import name views - Django App Template Addition

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to develop my own project alongside the Codeschool [program](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/try-django/level/2/section/1/the-template-of-doom) introducing Django. I've gotten to the point where I want to implement a template for my landing page in templates folder at:

```
C:\Users\****\****\ph_main\templates
```

I am able to return html via the views.py file without templates via:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello!')
```

As soon as I add my application to the settings.py file. I receive an error that returns:

```
File "C:\Users\****\****\ph_main\migrations\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
        from . import views
    ImportError: cannot import name views
```

urls.py contains

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index)
    ]
```

Comment: Questions like this are easier when you show the layout of the files in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `urls.py` shouldn't be in the migrations folder. Move it back into the `ph_main` folder.

You will have to update references from `ph_main.migrations.urls` to `ph_main.urls` at the same time.

Comment: It appears that this fixed it. I removed the urls.py from the migrations file and it appears to have automatically changed the references. I genuinely appreciate your help.